# Horizontally center text within a div

Tags: css

I observe that `text-align: center`, while creating equal space around the left and right of the text from its container block element's boundaries (`div` in this case), also changes the alignment of the text to `center`. In this, it violates the *Single Responsibility Principal*.

**With `text-align: center`**

[image]

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
  
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a long piece of text that runs into many lines of reading. Some people like to sleep, and some like to drink water. This is looking like a poem. It is even aligned like one. What a pity!</div>
```

A few things to note for the casual reader:

1. I am not asking how to *vertically* align text.
2. I know I can do what I want if I took a `div` within a `div`. I am not asking for alternate solutions to a problem I am trying to solve. I am asking if there is a way to do it without resorting to a kludge such as taking a containing `div`.

**With a kludge: taking a div inside a div**

[image]

```css
body > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
  padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
}

div > div {
  text-align: justify;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>This is a long piece of text that runs into many lines of reading. Some people like to sleep, and some like to drink water. This is NOT looking like a poem. Oh, so nice! But it uses a hack, what the fack!</div>
<div>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to horizontally center text within a containing block such as a div while retaining the *text alignment* to `left` or `justify`.

Comment: what is wrong with having an extra div? css is not some magical tool that can do everything to one element.  Anyway in your second example with the second div, you can just remove it and put the justify on the parent

Comment: What's wrong in using `text-align: left;` in first example? It solves the problem without a nested div.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi My apologies. That is because of the carefully applied padding. My question really is: is there an inbuilt property or method to retain the text alignment while centering it *without having to do the calculation like padding, margin, etc.* yourself?

Comment: What should be the rule for how wide you want the content to be? Would you want to specify that explicitly?

Comment: Ofc not, at least something needs to be added/defined.

Comment: @k-nut You're right. I never thought about that. That settles it. Your comment along with that of RajenderJoshi's.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi You're right. Please see the last few comments.

Comment: @k-nut Could you please write down an answer. That is an insight and a subtle one that needs to be recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't and for a good reason. For if there were to be one such inbuilt solution within the CSS engine itself, without you setting the padding, *who would decide how wide the text content must be*?

Your best bet is to do what you were already doing. That is, to set the padding on the left and right sides, and to leave `text-align: justify` (or `left` as you please). That would do exactly what you wanted.

---

The problem with the approach that you are thinking of is that you somehow need to define how wide the centered text should be. In you're example you were setting the `padding` and the `width` and by that implicitly setting the width that was left for the text in the middle.

The only real solution to making sure that something only takes a predefined with in a container is actually creating a DOM-element for it. This means that you probably can't avoid the extra `div` here if you do not want to use the `padding`/`width` hack.

Comment: @Water Cooler v2 thanks for the more eloquent rephrasing/addition!